# how do i extract the token from authorization header inside my resource file?[jersey API]

Tags: api, web-applications, jersey

i would like to extract the token of the client who sent the request inside my resource file, to be exact in the function in order to give the appropriate response.
for instance in here:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Customer_api> getAllCustomers()  {
    return CustomerService.getAllCustomer();
}
```

I would like to extract the authorization header of the request after this function receives the request.
using jersey to create an api.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use the Jersey security context 
[more description](https://simplapi.wordpress.com/2015/09/19/jersey-jax-rs-securitycontext-in-action/)